# PHP: File uploads with 0 filesize

Tags: php

I have a form to upload images:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="imgUpload" class="admin_img_txt">
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="img01" class="admin_img_btn">
</form>
```

It posts to self with code included on an `img01` post.  That process works, but when I echo the `$_FILES` array, I do not have a file size.  The image I am uploading is a valid jpg that I have on my local machine.  It returns

```
(
[imgUpload] => Array
    (
        [name] => testjpg.jpg
        [type] => image/jpeg
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php3TxfDe
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 0
    )
)
```

I've verified the settings on my php.ini file.  It allows for up to 8mb files, which this is nowhere near.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  Here is the php.  I didn't include it as the print_r preceded all of it, so I did not think it to be significant.

```
if(isset($_POST["img01"])) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo  '</pre>';
    $filename = $_FILES["imgUpload"]["name"];
    $file_basename = substr($filename, 0, strripos($filename, '.'));
    $file_ext = substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.'));
    $ven_imgname = "$ven_id" . "_001";
    $newfilename = md5($ven_imgname) . $file_ext;
    $filesize = $_FILES["imgUpload"]["size"];
    $allowed_file_types = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif'); 
    if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 200000)) {
        if (file_exists("../img/venues/$ven_imgname.$file_ext")) {
            echo "You have already uploaded this file - $ven_imgname.$file_ext";
        } else {        
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgUpload"]["temp_name"], "../img/venues/" . $newfilename);
            echo "File uploaded successfully.";     
        }
    } else {
        echo "File upload failed."; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `echo filesize("testjpg.jpg");` return?

Comment: can you add the `php` code here which you tried??

Comment: code seems to be ok, have you tried with another image?

Comment: @DishaV. It happens with all images.

Comment: I just tried running your code and it actually working.. uploading images as well as did not show size = 0. There is one thing you have to change-: change `$_FILES["imgUpload"]["temp_name"]` to `$_FILES["imgUpload"]["tmp_name"]` in `move_uploaded_file`

Comment: @suyog Interesting, and thanks for the catch on tmp_name.  By your indication, this sounds like an OS/permissions type issue.  I'm currently uploading this from my Win7 PC to a LAMP box that is hosted on VirtualBox on the same PC.  I wonder if that may be the issue.  I'll try it from a remote PC.